# Voice Channel Stats Bot with specific roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

*Hey I tried to create a Voice Channel Stats Bot but I get the problem that I can't filter by certain group filters so that only the valorant role is counted when someone enters and leaves the server.*

**GuildMemberAddEvent**

```js
const BaseEvent = require('../utils/structures/BaseEvent');
module.exports = class GuildMemberAddEvent extends BaseEvent {
  constructor() {
    super('guildMemberAdd');
  }
  
  async run(client, member) {
  if (member.guild.id !== config.serverid) return;
  
  client.channels.cache.get(config.wolvesc).setName(` Wölfe: ${member.guild.roles.cache.get("718011794723176491").members.size}`);
  client.channels.cache.get(config.teamc).setName(` Team: ${member.guild.roles.cache.get("721922261560590408").members.size}`);
  client.channels.cache.get(config.boosterc).setName(` Boosters: ${member.guild.roles.cache.get("718231071442862121").members.size}`);
  }
}
```

**GuildMemberRemoveEvent**

```js
const BaseEvent = require('../utils/structures/BaseEvent');
module.exports = class GuildMemberRemoveEvent extends BaseEvent {
  constructor() {
    super('guildMemberRemove');
  }
  
  async run(client, member) {
  if (member.guild.id !== config.serverid) return;
  
  client.channels.cache.get(config.wolvesc).setName(` Wölfe: ${member.guild.roles.cache.get("718011794723176491").members.size}`);
  client.channels.cache.get(config.teamc).setName(` Team: ${member.guild.roles.cache.get("721922261560590408").members.size}`);
  client.channels.cache.get(config.boosterc).setName(` Boosters: ${member.guild.roles.cache.get("718231071442862121").members.size}`);
  }
}
```

*Thanks for anyone who can help me with this.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I found it out by myself again, so it's silly to ask here, but for all those who need an updated version, I'll write it under this post, have fun programming.*

**ready.js**

```js
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(process.env.DISCORD_SERVER_ID);

    const wolvesCount = client.channels.cache.get(process.env.DISCORD_CHANNEL_WOLVES);
    const teamCount = client.channels.cache.get(process.env.DISCORD_CHANNEL_TEAM);
    const boosterCount = client.channels.cache.get(process.env.DISCORD_CHANNEL_BOOSTER);

    setInterval(function() {

    var wolvesRole = guild.roles.cache.get(process.env.DISCORD_ROLE_WOLVES).members.size;
    var teamRole = guild.roles.cache.get(process.env.DISCORD_ROLE_TEAM).members.size;
    var boosterRole = guild.roles.cache.get(process.env.DISCORD_ROLE_BOOSTER).members.size;

    wolvesCount.setName(" Wölfe: " + wolvesRole)
    .catch(console.error);

    teamCount.setName(" Team: " + teamRole)
    .catch(console.error);

    boosterCount.setName(" Booster: " + boosterRole)
    .catch(console.error);
    }, 30000)
```